# Match height of another element on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

Ok, so I'm trying to get an element to be the full height of a page. My html element is matching the pages size even when I resize or open up the inspect element box and close it, but my body and other elements won't, so instead I am using javascript to make my element the size of the html box, which works, but when you resize the browser window or close/open the developer tools, the html element resizes but the other element doesn't.

Is there some way to add a listener on my html element to run a function when it changes height?

Here is some code I've tried using what someone suggested but doesn't work:

```
$('#program-cell').height($('html').height());
$('html').resize(function () {
    $('#program-cell').height($('html').height());
});
```

After adding the .resize() plugin one of the answers suggested I was able to get it almost working. When opening and closing the developer tools it works, but resizing the window didn't change anything. I guess because I am matching the size of the html element, the html element will grow though to match the size of the object I'm resizing, which means it will only get bigger and never smaller.

I had to clear out the height of the object I'm resizing by setting it's height to auto, then match the height of the html. I finally got it working, and here is the code that works:

```
$('#program-cell').height(($('html').height()-84)+'px');
$('html').resize(function () {
    $('#program-cell').height('auto');
    $('#program-cell').height(($('html').height()-84)+'px');
});
```

I have the -84 to subtract the height of my header.

Comment: some code please .........

Comment: [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).

Comment: I tried the .resize but perhaps it only works on window? not for elements?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Is the problem that the page scrolls? Do you want the height of everything to be confined to the window?

Comment: I wanted to know if there was some way to add a listener on my html element to run a function when it changes height. There is, with a plugin that one of the answers linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a plugin to add listeners for element resizing that you can use to do just that. Check it out [here.](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/)

Alternately, `.resize()` works on window.

Comment: Nice plugin. It doesn't take care of the window resizing, but it does take care of opening and closing the developer tools box.

Comment: Can you use it to call `.resize()` on your parent element that's changing size with the div, and then put your javascript/jQuery inside a function in resize? Something like `(changing_div).resize(function_to_do_some_resizing)`

Comment: Ok, I got it working using this. The problem was the height of the html was being changed by the height of the object I'm editing, so I had to make it small again in order to get the height of the html. It's hard to explain, I'll post my code in my question.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need JavaScript at all.

```css
html, body { height:100%; }
div { height:100%; }
```

```html
<html> <!-- 100% of window height -->
    <body> <!-- 100% of html height -->
        <div></div> <!-- 100% of body height -->
    </body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LpxSC/).

If your divider's parent has a value which isn't 100% height your divider will not have 100% height relative to the page body.

```html
<html> <!-- 100% of window height -->
    <body> <!-- 100% of html height -->
        <div style="height:30px"> <!-- 30px high parent -->
            <div></div> <!-- 100% of parent height = 30px -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried it that way, but my div is very nested and body wasn't changing it's height, digging into it would take too long and I'm on a deadline.

Comment: I've given an example to prove that this works. Down voting my answer because you're not prepared to put some time into solving your problem is a pretty lame thing to do, too. Your nested divider with 100% height will have 100% height of it's parent. If your 100% height divider's parent only has 30px height, for example, your 100% height divider will only be 30px high.

Comment: Downvoting? I didn't down vote anything... I'm the one asking the question here, I'm all ears for any and every potential solution!

Comment: I understand how the nesting works with 100% height, that's why I didn't want to do that because I'd have to add 100% to every element it's nested in, and like I said, it's very nested. As well I can't even get the first element it's nested in to work, so it just seemed much simpler to use javascript and force it.

Comment: Using JavaScript you'd be increasing the size of the elements its nested in anyway. You may as well just set the height on all the elements its nested in. `div#parent, div#parent div { height:100%; }` Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/LpxSC/1/. Otherwise you'd be giving yourself more work in the long run catering for users who have scripts disabled.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the javascript solution might end up being harder than the css solution.

Comment: I appreciate the response so I upvoted you, but I ended up using the javascript solution.

Comment: No worries. Sorry for accusing you of down voting.